# vuejs - setInterval not working with vue-worker

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to use `setInterval` in `vue-worker` but the interval function is not running inside the worker.

```
Countdown(){
    this.$worker.run(() => {
    let vm = this;
      vm.worker= setInterval(() => {
        vm.countDown--;

        if (this.countDown === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.worker);
          this.retrieveDrawingResult();
        }
      }, 1000);
  })
    .then(console.log) 
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

The `vue-worker` is running for other functions except running `setInterval` , are there any solutions ???

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different solution, without vue-worker, but it works.

The implementation steps are as follows
Because vue-cli is used, it is necessary to install worker-loader dependencies under webpack to load worker.js separately.

```
npm install worker-loader --save-dev
```

Change the configuration items of the vue.config.js file

```
configureWebpack:{
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.worker\.js$/,
                loader: 'worker-loader',
                options: {
                  inline: true,
                  fallback: false,
                  name: '[name]:[hash:8].js'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Note that the worker-loader configuration item must be written in front of js-loader, otherwise an error will be reported.
Write the encapsulation method below. In order to adapt to the multi-timer situation, you need to build a class.

```
/**
 * worker class
 * export Timer method
 * 
 */
export class workerTimer {
    constructor(){
         
    }
    timeInterval(name,interval,_this){
        console.log(name+'The timer has been set up');   
        this[name] = setInterval(() => {
            _this.postMessage({name:name,message:interval/1000+'Seconds arrived.'})
        },Number(interval))
    }
}
```

This class is then invoked using the worker main method, e for the incoming timer array within the component

```
import {workerTimer} from './workerTimer'
/**
 *Traversing parameters through traversers
 *new Create new worker classes
 *Call the timer method
 */
self.onmessage = function (e) {
    e.data.map((item) => {
      let workertimer = new workerTimer()
      workertimer.timeInterval(item.name,item.interval,self)
    })
};
Introducing worker into vue components
import Worker from './worker.js'
Write a method in methods, and the name starts at random.
workerInit(){
    this.worker = new Worker();
    this.worker.postMessage(this.workerList);
    this.worker.onmessage = (params) => {
        ...
    }
},
Create a variable in data in the following format:
workerList:[
    {name:'snapInterval',interval:10000},
    {name:'intervalFunc',interval:40}
],
Call the worker method within a hook
mounted(){
    this.workerInit()
}
```

Above, the work with two timers is set up, and callbacks can be triggered within the main thread by the name returned by the worker.
It's also easy to destroy the worker, just write it in the hook when destroy happens.

```
this.worker.terminate();
```

[The solution is taken from here](https://programming.vip/docs/running-interval-timer-with-worker-in-vue-environment.html)